# Activerecord: querying records whose associations have all requested properties when combined, but single association does not have all properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models similar to this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties
end


class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: properties
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  thing_id      :integer          not null
#  property_1    :boolean
#  property_2    :boolean
```

I need a way to find all `things` that have any combination of property fields without regards in which Property record (as long as they have all). For example, I need to get all `things` that have both property_1 and property_2 set to true, but it does not have to be in the same Property record.

```
thing = Thing.create

Property.create thing: thing, property_1: true
Property.create thing: thing, property_2: true

# I want to achieve something like this but with less queries 
# (also my actual models are of course more complex 
# so something like this is not practical nor efficient)
thing_ids = Property.where(property_1: true).pluck(:thing_id) & 
  Property.where(property_2: true).pluck(:thing_id)
```

It is relatively simple to do it in ruby by processing partial results produced by activerecord, but I would like to let the db do as much heavy lifting as possible. Is it possible to achieve this in less clumsy way only with activerecord?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to do it in one query.

```
thing_ids = Thing.joins(
  'INNER JOIN properties p1 on p1.thing_id = things.id and p1.property_1 = true',
  'INNER JOIN properties p2 on p2.thing_id = things.id and p2.property_2 = true'
).pluck(:id).uniq
```